# nmap: what does "state = closed" means

Tags: nmap

I am trying nmap command on two remote hosts public ip address

```
~ % nmap (remote host1 - public ip)
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-23 20:08 EDT
Nmap scan report for openrg (remote host1 - public ip)
Host is up (0.0093s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
443/tcp  open  https
515/tcp  open  printer
631/tcp  open  ipp
4567/tcp open  tram
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8443/tcp open  https-alt


~ % nmap (remote host2 - public ip)
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-23 20:09 EDT
Nmap scan report for (remote host2 - public ip)
Host is up (0.023s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
445/tcp  closed microsoft-ds
8000/tcp open   http-alt
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

I am looking for the port `8080`

in `host1` it shows `STATE = open` and in `host2` it shows `STATE = closed`

what does `http-proxy` means here.

Answer (score 3):

`nmap` tries to tell the type of service (process running) that is listening the port based on well-known services. That means that the service it is running on 8080 is "probably" an http-proxy server. This recognition is based on a database that associates the port number with this service, so it does not guarantee it is an http-proxy indeed, but guess it.

See [Nmap Service and Version Detection](https://nmap.org/book/man-version-detection.html).

The `closed` state means that the port is accessible from nmap probe packets but there is no application listening on it. See [Nmap Port Scanning Basics](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html)

Comment: so here `http-proxy` is just a guess and may or may not be the original service

Comment: also, `closed` does not mean that the `port is blocked by isp like verizon`